# Angular Ivy (8-beta): How to Inject HttpClient into Component?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build an example application to test Angular Ivy in combination with Angular Elements, but i can't find any information on how DI should be configured in that setting - since app.module is bypassed.

main.ts:

```
import { ɵrenderComponent as renderComponent } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
renderComponent(AppComponent);
```

app.module.ts: **this is not used by main.ts, so where should HttpClientModule be loaded and custom elements be defined?**

```
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http/http';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';

import { AppComponent } from 'src/app/app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [ HttpClientModule ],
    entryComponents: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

    ngDoBootstrap() {
        customElements.define('app-component',
            createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: this.injector }));
    }
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        http.get<any>('someurl').subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }
}
```

This results in the following exception:

> Error: Injector: NOT_FOUND [HttpClient]

I've read some hints about a 'deps' property for @Component, but it's not found (~8.0.0-beta.8). I tried adding `providers: [ { provide: HttpClient } ]` to @Component, which throws

> Error: Injector: NOT_FOUND [HttpHandler]

`providers: [ { provide: HttpClient, deps: [HttpHandler] } ]` still throws the same exception.

Where should i configure dependencies when using Ivy? And while at it, where should `createCustomElement` be called?

I added a github repository with a minimal, complete and verifiable example: https://github.com/markusdresch/ng-ivy-custom-element

**EDIT**
Alright, i got a little further. HttpHandler has to be provided more explicitly (this is in @Component):

```
  providers: [
    { provide: HttpClient, deps: [ HttpHandler ] },
    { provide: HttpHandler, useValue: new HttpXhrBackend({ build: () => new XMLHttpRequest() }) },
    // ...
  ]
```

This way the above errors are gone and it works. However, i'm still not sure how to register the custom element.

Comment: I’m also curious how you’d use another nested angular component... no declaration blocks, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question: It's possible to fire up the root injector in main.ts. It's not that straight forward as @NgModule, because dependencies have to be provided as well:

in main.ts:

```
const injector: Injector = Injector.create({
  name: 'root',
  providers: [
    { provide: HttpClient, deps: [ HttpHandler ] },
    { provide: HttpHandler, useValue: new HttpXhrBackend({ build: () => new XMLHttpRequest() }) },
  ]
});

renderComponent(AppComponent, { injector: injector });
```

I haven't really solved creating a custom element like this though, with the exception of this hack:

```
class AppComponentCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    renderComponent(AppComponent, { injector: injector });
  }
}

customElements.define('ng-ivy-custom-element', AppComponentCustomElement);
```

But this way @Inputs etc have to be routed through manually. I'll keep tinkering and update if i find something more usable.

**UPDATE:** according to https://juristr.com/blog/2019/05/Angular-8-and-the-Future-NGConf-2019-Roundup/#not-every-app-is-a-spa my attempt is not considered a hack, but the right way to achieve this.

Answer (score -2):

To provide module dependencies in any component, define a module in the same component file as shown below.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Here `ivy renderer` resolve HttpClient from app module.